# Convert std::vector<bool> to std::string

Tags: c++

I have a vector of binary data and would like to convert this into a string. How can I go about this task. Just to be clear I and not looking to have a string of just 1's and 0's. I want it so that every 8 entries equal one char.

Comment: This is a trivial coding task. If the question really is whether the standard provides a way to do this efficiently, the answer is no.

Comment: I'm new to c++ and this doesn't seem trivial to me. I've searched extensively and cant find anything on converting vector<bool> to a string.

Comment: I saw that bitset had a to_string method but that doesn't do what I'm looking for and I wont know the size at run time so it's not an option anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the bits and use the bitwise operators to place them into `char` values.

There's nothing particularly tricky about this. If you're unfamiliar with bitwise arithmetic, you might try implementing it first in a more familiar language and then translate it to C++ as an exercise.

```
std::size_t divide_rounding_up( std::size_t dividend, std::size_t divisor )
    { return ( dividend + divisor - 1 ) / divisor; }

std::string to_string( std::vector< bool > const & bitvector ) {
    std::string ret( divide_rounding_up( bitvector.size(), 8 ), 0 );
    auto out = ret.begin();
    int shift = 0;

    for ( bool bit : bitvector ) {
        * out |= bit << shift;

        if ( ++ shift == 8 ) {
            ++ out;
            shift = 0;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm not very familiar with bitwise. I haven't had much experience with binary data yet. I'll be sure to read up on it.

Comment: The following line is giving me a bit of trouble. std::string ret( divide_rounding_up( bitvector.size(), 8 ), 0 );. I'm getting the error invalid conversion from std::size_t to const char*. Also what is that line doing? I can see that it's calling the other function which returns a number. Is this presetting the size of the string?

Comment: Never mind the error is gone now. I copied it wrong. Sorry. I'm still curious as to what it's doing though.

Comment: @Kahless It's initializing a `std::string` to have ceil(bitvector.size()/8) characters all initialized to zero. (It might be more clear to say `'\0'` instead of `0`.)